# custom UINavigationController and UIBarbuttonItem

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

i have the following code to customize UINavigationController :

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)  

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  
{  
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.png"];  

[image drawInRect:rect];  
}
```

this works great but i want also in the same time change the background of items in navigationbar like (back and refresh ...)to the same background of navigationbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the drawRect methods for UIBarButtonItem? Also, you can always set the customView of a UIBarButtonItem to a UIButton and set the background of the UIButton to the same as the one of the UINavigationBar.